# Can I keep threads alive and give them other workloads?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Suppose I create threads with `pthreads`, is it possible to send them new things to work on **after** they have been initialized, so I don't waste resources in creating new threads? For instance, I create 3 threads, thread 2 signals completion and I send it another "task" without killing it and starting a new one. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and that is what servers like Apache do to increase their performance. The design pattern is called the [Thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) and there are various implementations ([this one](http://people.clarkson.edu/~jmatthew/cs644.archive/cs644.fa2001/proj/locksmith/code/ExampleTest/threadpool.c) for example) using pthreads.

Of course, you might want to keep your implementation as simple as possible, depending on what your goals are.

Answer (score 5):

The usual, simple form is an ordinary (work) [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29). In principle, you maintain a queue structure, perhaps as a linked list, protected by a mutex. Typically, [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarCreation) are used by the main/producer threads to notify worker threads that new work is available, so they don't have to poll.

Some previous SO questions that may also be useful are:

- [How To Use Condition Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206350/how-to-use-condition-variable)
- [One producer, Two consumers and usage of pthread_cond_signal & pthread_mutex_lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123437/one-producer-two-consumers-and-usage-of-pthread-cond-signal-pthread-mutex-loc)
- [pthread conditional variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525478/pthread-conditional-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. For example, you can use producer-consumer pattern. Here is an [example in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656404/c-sharp-producer-consumer), but it can be easily implemented in pthreads as well.

Answer (score 0):

The search-keyword to your question is "thread pooling" or "thread pool". Using this terms you will find plenty information on this site and also in Google.